# How to ffmpeg resize 2.7k DJI Phantom Standard video to 1080p good quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i :

```
Duration: 00:01:59.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 39988 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 39984 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-05-22 11:04:26
  handler_name    : DJI.AVC
  encoder         : Dji AVC encoder
```

I used:

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0002.MOV -vf scale=1920:1080 DJI_0002FullHD.MOV
```

But the output quality is much worse than it should be.

How to improve the quality?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your FFmpeg build is recent and has x264 linked, use

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0002.MOV -vf "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 DJI_0002FullHD.MOV
```